# Here Maps screen on Nokia X device shows a white screen with logo only

Tags: android, here-api, nokiax

I have followed all steps mentioned in the porting guide for V1.

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />


<meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
        android:value="id here" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
        android:value="token here" />

<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" />
<uses-library
        android:name="com.here.android"
        android:required="false" />

<activity
        android:name=".ui.maps.HereLocationsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

I have added hardwareAcceleration to application tag as well.

It shows location markers properly without map tiles.

What could be the issuw. I am testing on a Nokia X device without SD card.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you replaced "id here" and "token here" with the values provided by Nokia? What does the logcat-output say? Sounds like an authorization issue, I had something similar with the Google Maps API once.

Answer (score 0):

the minSdkVersion should be also changed to be 11, you do need to set the Id & token to values reserved for you

As well as do add following permissions as well:

- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Also do try zooming out, could indeed be that you are located in a area which is shown in white and having full zoom there..

Basically it should be black if the initialization fails, and it should be blue if there is no tiles (or you are at sea), white background thus would indeed be inddicating something else going wrong.

Do also make sure you have enabled location, and have working mobile internet. Would also suggest opening HERE maps app, and downlaoding the maps tiles for the same location used in the app, thus you could see that how it is supposed to look like.

Comment: The 2 permissions have been put..Sorry I forgot to add them here. I tried setting the Min SDK to 11 but it didnt work. I have a working internet connection which I have verified as well. ID and Token have been inserted as well just not shown in the snapshot